# Android - How to co-ordinate Spinner and Fragments when going back?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-spinner, fragment-backstack

I have a `Spinner` in my activity which works very simply: When the user selects an item in the spinner, the appropriate `Fragment` is shown in the activity by replacing the previously-shown fragment.

My spinner uses a `SimpleCursorAdapter`. And each fragment transaction is added to the back stack.

Everything works fine when selecting spinner items, but when I press the device's **BACK** button, the spinner selection is not updated.

I see `FragmentManager` has an `addOnBackStackChangedListener()` method, but I'm not sure if that is the best way to go (or if it could even work at all)...

So is there a convenient (or other) way to co-ordinate the spinner's selection with the current fragment when going back?

**NB** - I suppose what I'm ideally looking for would be some kind of `Spinner`/`Fragment` equivalent of the `TabLayout`/`ViewPager`'s `tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)` method.

Comment: It sounds like a bad UX idea to add a Spinner selection to the back stack while keeping the spinner on screen. It should always be immediately clear where the back button will bring the user back.

Comment: Yes, good point. Some of the first level fragments (that I referred to in my question) are ListFragments that lead to a second level fragment being shown, so I'm now only adding those second level transactions to the back stack. Thank you.